# pandas cannot converge

Tags: python, pandas

I get an error that a file does not exist while I have the file there in the folder, would you please tell me where I am making a mistake?

```
 pd.DataFrame.from_csv
```

I am getting an error shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 194, in <module>
    start_path+end_res)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/script/mergeT.py", line 5, in merge
    df_peak = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(peak_score, index_col = False, sep='\t')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1231, in from_csv
    infer_datetime_format=infer_datetime_format)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 388, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 729, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 922, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1389, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4175)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parse**strong text**r.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:8440)
IOError: File results\scoring\fed\score_peak.txt does not exist
```

I have tried to set a path to the exact file 
for example

Comment: The first error: wrong indentation of the script. Then: backslaches instead of slashes. Likely you use an outdated file, perhaps, configured in Windows.

Comment: Like @user3159253 said you need to indent everything after the function `def` line, otherwise the file path won't be changed.

Comment: @user3159253 do you mean I import the data like peak_score = '\Users\admin\Desktop\peak_score.txt' ? yes it was based on windows and now I am using Mac

Comment: @Greg Lever thanks, can you be more specific? to be honest I could not understand

Comment: Now the error means that Panda's parser can't load file. Are you sure that the file contains correct data at correct places? I suppose there could be column mismatching or something like this.

Comment: @user3159253 I am 100% sure. I did a test now, I copied the script to the desktop and then the two files also. I ran it and I got no error. where would my results be saved?

Comment: If you have a file that could be parsed in one installation of the library, and couldn't in another, I would bet that the reason is the difference of versions of the installations. As the script shows, the result should be saved in `res_file`

Comment: @user3159253 what is your suggestion? I am still struggling with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation of pandas 0.19.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html) `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv` does not support `index_col = False`. Try to use `pandas.read_csv` instead (with the same parameters). Also make sure you are using the up to date version of pandas.

See if this works:

```
import pandas as pd
def merge(peak_score, profile_score, res_file):
    df_peak = pd.read_csv(peak_score, index_col = False, sep='\t')
    df_profile = pd.read_csv(profile_score, index_col = False, sep='\t')
    result = pd.concat([df_peak, df_profile], axis=1)
    print result.head()
    test = []
    for a,b in zip(result['prot_a_p'],result['prot_b_p']):
        if a == b:
            test.append(1)
        else:
            test.append(0)
    result['test']=test
    result = result[result['test']==0] 
    del result['test']
    result = result.fillna(0)
    result.to_csv(res_file)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Regarding the path issue when changing from Windows to OS X:

In all flavours of Unix, paths are written with slashes `/`, while in Windows backslashes `\` are used. Since OS X is a descendant of Unix, as other users have correctly pointed out, when you change there from Windows you need to adapt your paths.